# why is this trait not object safe?

Tags: rust

i'm making a game in rust and need to make a vector of `UiElements` to loop over and handle inputs or drawing.

so i create a `UiElement` trait, pass it into a vector and says my trait is not object safe.

i have tried putting `dyn UiElement` in a box and that still doesn't work. I've also replaced the return types for the trait methods to i32(maybe it's just strings and vectors are buggy with traits) even that didn't work

i have also read https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety to check if my trait follows all the rules

here is code

element.rs

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum Rect {
    Color(ColorRect),
    Image(ImageRect)
}

pub trait UiElement: Debug + Clone {
    fn get_id(&self) -> String;
    fn get_rects(&self) -> Vec<Rect>;
}
```

game.rs

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Game {
    ui_elements: Vec<Box<dyn UiElement>>, //problem here
    color_rects: Vec<ColorRect>,
    image_rects: Vec<ImageRect>
}
```

Comment: It's not object safe because it has `Clone` as a supertrait, and `Clone` isn't object safe.

Comment: If you need `Clone` functionality, _there is a crate for that_: [dyn-clone](https://crates.io/crates/dyn-clone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed `Clone` as suggested in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74178811/why-is-this-trait-not-object-safe#comment130967743_74178811) :

> It's not object safe because it has Clone as a supertrait, and Clone isn't object safe.

*trait.rs*

```rust
pub trait UiElement: Debug {
    fn get_id(&self) -> String;
    fn get_rects(&self) -> Vec<Rect>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Cezarhg2007 suggests, you can remove `Clone` from the definition, but that does not mean you need to give up on cloning. Since you manipulate `Box<dyn UiElement>` and not just `UiElement`, you can define the clone method on the former by using a potential clone method on the latter.

*trait.rs*

```
pub trait UiElement: Debug {
    fn get_id(&self) -> String;
    fn get_rects(&self) -> Vec<Rect>;
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn UiElement>; // implemented as Box::new(self.clone()) in classes
}

impl Clone for Box<dyn UiElement> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.clone_box()
    }
}
```